# Gettting ERC-20 token transfer count over an API

Tags: erc-20, external-api

I am building a service to monitor token activity. Does any service have an API to get the transfer count of a ERC-20 token? I am not interested in individual `Transfer` events, only their count.

Comment: yes, etherscan api

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think you can use this Api to fetch all the transfer token data

```
curl --request GET \
     --url 'https://api.chainbase.online/v1/token/transfers?chain_id=1&contract_address=0x7d1afa7b718fb893db30a3abc0cfc608aacfebb0&page=1&limit=20' \
     --header 'accept: application/json' \
     --header 'x-api-key: demo'
```

And here is the doc and details about how to use it.
[https://docs.chainbase.com/docs/how-to-get-all-erc20-transfers-by-contract](https://docs.chainbase.com/docs/how-to-get-all-erc20-transfers-by-contract?utm_source=daidai)